# javascript: it keeps copying the 1st div it duplicates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a script that will copy the entire div into the another div and it's working.

Here's the code:

script:

```
var a = 1;
    function add() 
    {
        var fContent = document.getElementById('1');
        var sContent = document.getElementById('2');
            if(a <=10)
            {
                a++;
                var objTo = document.getElementById('m')
                var divtest = document.createElement("div"); 
                divtest.innerHTML = (sContent.innerHTML = a + fContent.innerHTML);
                objTo.appendChild(divtest);
            }
    }
```

html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="add();" value="+" />

<div id="m">

<div id="1">
test
</div>
<div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

as you run the code it works but the main issue is it keeps duplicating the 1st content above:

OUTPUT:

> 1st OUTPUT:

```
test
2 test
2 test
```

> 2nd OUTPUT:

```
test
3 test
2 test
3 test
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> 1st OUTPUT:

```
test
2 test
```

> 2nd OUTPUT:

```
test
2 test
3 test
```

Comment: Try `divtest.innerHTML = a + fContent.innerHTML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected javascript. Try now. Instead + you had = in the code

```
var a = 1;
function add() {

    var fContent = document.getElementById('1');
    var sContent = document.getElementById('2');
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var objTo = document.getElementById('m');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = (sContent.innerHTML + a + fContent.innerHTML);
        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

Here is the demo [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rrLmz3Lv/)

Comment: like that simple. i never tried it haha. thanks alot.